# How to use 'due date' in some situation?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I want to use 'due date' in the following sentence:

```
They learn how to solve their problems in the due date.
```

I doubt that whether 'in the due date' is correct or not. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

> They learn how to solve their problems **by** the due date.

Should this question be on ELL SE?